# Download Sharepoint Online file using Python

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to automate some work processes by using Python to download an Excel file from our SharePoint site.  Some background is that I'm fairly new to Python and am mostly self-taught.  I have read over many examples here using sharepy, office365, requests, etc. and none seem to work.  Below is what I have tried (basically copied from another example) with the error below that:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File

#Inputs
url_shrpt = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsite"
username_shrpt = "user@company.com"
password_shrpt = "password"
folder_url_shrpt = "sites/teamsite/library"

#Authentication
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url_shrpt)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username_shrpt, password_shrpt):
    ctx = ClientContext(url_shrpt, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authenticated into sharepoint as: ",web.properties['Title'])

else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())

#Function for extracting the file names from a folder
global print_folder_contents
def print_folder_contents(ctx, folder_url):
    try:

        folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_url)
        fold_names = []
        sub_folders = folder.files 
        ctx.load(sub_folders)
        ctx.execute_query()

        for s_folder in sub_folders:

            fold_names.append(s_folder.properties["Name"])

        return fold_names

    except Exception as e:
        print('Problem printing out library contents: ', e)
######################################################


# Call the function by giving your folder URL as input  
filelist_shrpt=print_folder_contents(ctx,folder_url_shrpt) 

#Print the list of files present in the folder
print(filelist_shrpt)
```

Here is the error I receive:
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /extSTS.srf (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

After collaborating with some more knowledgeable coworkers, I was told it might be a permissions issue; but I'm not sure how to verify that.  Any help and/or advice would be appreciated.